# Need List all items in calculated column of another list

Tags: list

Need To subtract *Holidays_list* items count if found in *start* - *end* date range columns of another List.

Formula May look like in *Calcluated Column*.

`Working_day-CountIf(holiday_list,date>=start_date,date<=end_date)`.

but holiday_list can't be able to retrive in caluclated column.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible out of the box (to use another list, even another item it the same list) Calculated column can only use same item fields), you would have to create custom app or workflow to calculate remaining leave based on the new entries.